# Querying a Struct in order to update UisearchController

Tags: ios, struct, swift2

I have a basic UITableviewController, UISearchResultsUpdating  and my data is kept in a Struct within an Array like this:

```
import UIKit

import Foundation


class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
struct Melody {
        let category : String
        let name : String
        let location : String
    }


let songs = [Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Mein Gott! nun ist e# wieder Morgen", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 367)"),
    Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Auf, auf‘ mein Geist! zu loben", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 358)"),
    Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Auf! ermunt‘re di¡ mein Sinn", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 455)"),
    Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Auf! meine Seel‘! und dank‘ dem Herren", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 454)"),
    Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Christe! Wahre# Seelenli¡t", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 359)"),
    Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Da# walte Gott! der mi¡ au# lauter Gnaden", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 360)"),
    Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Die Na¡t ist nun dahin", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 361)"),
    Melody(category: "Morgen Lieder", name: "Du heilige Dreifältigkeit", location: "Lutheris¡ Gesangbu¡ (Lied 682)"),]

var filteredSongs = [Melody]()

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

now after search functions code and IF statements, I'm trying to write a function to update my UiSearchController like this;

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(sear,chController: UISearchController)
    {
        self.filteredSongs.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

        let array = (Melody as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

        self.filteredSongs = array as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

but I get an error: "SearchTableViewController.Melody.type" is not convertible to "NSArray" on the line

```
let array = (Melody as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

So how do I convert my Struct to an NSArray, or how do I update my SearchController when my data is inside a Struct?

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Melody as NSArray -> songs as! NSArray

Comment: Hi Quang, It still wouldn't accept it....Can you provide the full line of code as an example please?

Answer (score 0):

replace your code

```
let array = (Melody as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

with

```
let array = songs.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```